# Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope

Tags: node.js

Всплывает ошибка Error: Promised response from onMessage listener went out of scope при запросе на сервер с клиента, если делать запрос через программу postman такой ошибки нет.
Код обработки запроса на сервере:

```js
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  console.log('klsafjdaksldfj')
  return res.json({mes: "USSS"})
})
```

Код запроса с клиента:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:5173/api/login', {
        firstName: 'Fred',
        lastName: 'Flintstone'
        })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Сервер и клиент работают на одном порту

Comment: Ошибка на клиенте или на сервере? Вы проверяли, что возвращает `return res.json({mes: "USSS"})`? а главное зачем возвращает?

Comment: Swad, да, проверял, возвращает обычный json {
    "mes": "USSS"
}, это пока просто проверка, в дальнейшем будет возвращать JWT токен

Comment: А ошибка да, на клиенте, до сервера запрос даже не доходит

Comment: Посмотрите вот [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69506506/what-does-error-promised-response-from-onmessage-listener-went-out-of-scope-m). Возможно это как раз ваша ошибка. В посте говорится, что это может так работать блокировщик рекламы и ваш сайт (localhost) надо где то добавить в доверительные

Comment: Извините, оказывается не из-за этой ошибки не происходит запрос на сервер, это просто какая-то левая ошибка никак не мешающая работе клиента, ошибка от axios: https://imgur.com/a/5rEFNgQ

Comment: Судя по ошибке axios считает что такой страницы нет, хотя при запросе через postman всё работает нормально, и возвращается нужный мне объект (фото: https://imgur.com/a/XNFklNW )